# Facebook wall posts made by me via the graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to query my feed for the wall posts made by me and not by others?

Comment: `/userid/posts` contains only your own posts. (OK, status messages created on your behalf, like for liking something or becoming friends with someone, as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.Try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
And use

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/your_facebook_id?fields=feed.fields(from,message,story,description)
```

Comment: I still get posts from my friends when the post om my wall